# Wordpress shortcode function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, custom-fields

Can anyone explain why this only returns the 1st result only. I want to return all results that have the same custom field value as the current url. It will ony return 1. Does it need a for each or something? Thank you!!

```
<?php add_shortcode( 'feed', 'display_custom_post_type' );

    function display_custom_post_type(){

    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $args = array( 
       'post_type'       => 'custom_post_type',
       'posts_per_page'  => -1  
    );

    $new_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();

    return get_title();

    endwhile;

};?>
```

Comment: I have removed the meta query from the example for simplicity. The same issue arrises with or without the meta query included. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have added the return inside the loop it will only display the last one. You have to place the return outside the loop for it to display all.

Just a small example to see it work, change this bit:

```
while($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();

return get_title();

endwhile;
```

to this:

```
while($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();

$all_titles .= get_title();

endwhile;

return $all_titles;
```

It will most probably show all the titles in a single row, so just format as you wish!

Answer (score 1):

You "return" from the function after the first element inside the while loop.

example returning all the posts:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1  

);
$results = get_posts($args);
return $results;
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my question. That doesn't solve the issue of the single return rather than returning multiple outputs.